# Prevent smartcard / hardware token from hanging NLA prompt when using RDP ActiveX Control

Tags: winapi, com, activex, rdp

If I have a hardware token / smartcard attached to the local system the `NLA` prompt will hang for 4 minutes when entering password or even canceling dialog.  This is both the Windows client and my app.

Is there an advanced setting in the `RDP ActiveX Client` to stop NLA from doing that?

I've already set `advancedSettings.put_RedirectSmartCards(FALSE);` through the `IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings8` interface but it makes no difference.

When I remove the token, everything works at full speed.   Sometimes even with the token attached, say after a reboot, it will work for a couple times, then back to 4 minute hangs.

It's the exact same thing experienced by others, see [this link](https://serverfault.com/a/1120027/999689)

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

The remote computer that you are trying to connect to require Network Level Authentication (NLA), but your Windows domain controller cannot be contacted to perform NLA. If you are an administrator on the remote computer, you can disable NLA by using the options on the Remote tab of the System Properties dialog box.

You could try to temporarily disable NLA. To disable NLA please use the below commands, or use the `DisableNLA` script in Run Command.

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp" /v UserAuthentication /t REG_DWORD /d 0`

To sign in with a smart card from a computer that is not joined to a domain, the smart card must contain the root certification of the domain controller.

The UPN in the certificate must include a domain that can be resolved. Otherwise, the Kerberos protocol cannot determine which domain to contact. You can resolve this issue by enabling GPO X509 domain hints.

Once you have resolved the issue re-enable NLA, by running the following commands:

`REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp" /v UserAuthentication /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

Refer to the Docs:

[Smart Card and Remote Desktop Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/smart-cards/smart-card-and-remote-desktop-services)

[Troubleshoot authentication errors when you use RDP to connect to Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/cannot-connect-rdp-azure-vm)

Comment: The token has nothing to do with login/etc and is locked.   If I remove the token on the local system I'm using, then the NLA works fast, it's only slow when it's in.

Comment: It seems that you could try disabling the NLA service to fix it.